# Hook state taking a while to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

I'm having an issue with updating hook state in my component. Basically when a user clicks on a button I update the state with setState to the id of that button. In addition after the button is clicked a modal will appear with some more data is dependent on the id which is in state. So every time I the id state changes or the modal is opened I call a useEffect to get the modal's data. This is where the problem begins. In the useEffect a function is called to get the modal data and is returned in a then promise. However, this function completes faster than state could update the id.
I'll try to explain it better in the code.

```
//Button which passes in the id.
<button className = {styles.item} onClick={() => handleAdd(item.myID)}>Click</button>

const handleAdd = (myID) => {
    //opens the modal and setID to the ID passed in from the button
    setIsOpen(true)
    setID(myID)
}
useEffect(()=>{
 //once isOpen is true and ID us updated get the data
 //if I console log ID here state will update right when the modal opens which is what i want
    console.log(id)
    let mounted = true
    getData().then(data=>{
        //however this console.log(id) will not update immediately
        console.log(id)
        if(mounted){
            setData(data)
        }
    })
    return () => {mounted = false}
},[id, isOpen])

async function getData(){
    console.log(id)//similarly if i console log here id will be immediate
    const query = await GetQuery()
    query.sort((a, b) => (a.createdAt < b.createdAt) ? 1 : -1);
    console.log(id)//this will not update immediately
    var modaldata = CreateModalContent()
    return modaldata
}
```

My question I guess is why does the console.log(id) happen immediately in the useEffect, but doesn't update immediately in the then promise of getData()

Comment: when the button is clicked, you set the state of two states, therefore the useEffect will run twice every button click, overall quite messy and probably not what you want. You should just call getData() in the handleAdd method?

Comment: I tried replicating your code as much as possible here in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-state-taking-a-while-to-update-u6xox) and I can't reproduce your results. I see `id` logged in both places.

Comment: I tried using your codesandbox, it looks like after clicking add, effect pre and getdata pre will console log immediately but after what seems to be a second getdata later and effect later will console log at least for me

Comment: That is correct. The "pre" logs are immediate, the "later" are about 3 seconds later.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please explain why the "later" effects happen about 3 seconds later? Is it caused by the await statement? And would it be possible for the later effects to happen immediately?

Comment: It happens "later" because it's asynchronous code. Asynchronous code isn't processed immediately, i.e. synchronously. The 3 second delay is to help simulate the asynchronous nature.

Comment: Ok, I just realized you're asking why code running in asynchronous callbacks and promise chains doesn't run synchronously. Sorry, I thought you were trying to say that `id` state hadn't updated for some reason. Well, isn't the fact that it's asynchronous code enough of a hint why it doesn't run immediately?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense thanks.